# Are anti-static bags needed for storing electronic components?

Tags: sensor, components, storage, antistatic

Should I keep the sensors in the anti-static bags or are the bags only needed when shipping?

As the anti-static bags are inconvenient and often too big to put the sensor into a compartment in my electronics box.

Comment: What kind of sensors do you have?

Comment: I think the main danger is when you take something out of the box because you might be charged up. So ground yourself before you pick up anything. I've padded my box with anti static foam. ICs are stuck in there in neat rows so they don't tumble when I move the box and bend pins. Same with any sensor boards with pin headers on the bottom, which means everything for use on breadboards. Things like ATMega2560 that are expensive and don't have pins to stick into the foam I keep in their bag, zip locked anti-static bags are great there.

Comment: Is there also a packet of dessicant ("Do not eat") in the bag? If so, you might need to check the manufacturer's datasheet about how to prepare the component before soldering. [Here's an example](https://optoi.com/attachment/get/up_111_14815377499983.pdf).

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Please don't answer questions in the comment field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "depends". Devices that have protection diodes on their inputs are probably OK to drop into normal plastic storage draws. Things that are super static sensitive like MOSFETs are probably best kept in their original antistatic packaging.